# Change Electron window background color without need to recreate window?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'd like to set the background color dynamically in an Electron window without recreating the window. For my purposes, simply setting the color of an element like  `body` with CSS is not sufficient unfortunately.

It appears that only [`BrowserView` has a `setBackgroundColor` function according to the documentation.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view#viewsetbackgroundcolorcolor-experimental)

`BrowserWindow` does have the function, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Is there any known alternative?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to set the `<html>` element's background color?

Comment: Yes but as I mentioned I can't simply set the color with CSS for my purposes. It breaks a certain Electron feature I am trying to use.

Comment: Which feature? You need to provide more information if you want help with this.

Comment: it works for me with `BrowserWindow.setBackgroundColor` (see my example below) if it doesn't work either, please tell us how exactly "it doesn't work"

Comment: Hmm please tell me what your breaking feature is. I've written electron apps and setting the body's BG color always sufficed.

Comment: `customButtonsOnHover` cannot show when setting a background color on an element like `body` - @pergy I tried doing the same exact thing, only getting the mainWindow using `remote` and setting it from the renderer and it had no effect.

Comment: @Slbox just tried that, it doesn't work for me from renderer either. Found a workaround though. I add it to my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me when applying background color on `BrowserWindow` directly.
It seems to be undocumented but it [exists](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/atom/browser/api/atom_api_browser_window.h#L73) (from [0.34.1](https://github.com/electron/electron/commit/e36d455d518cf79bc06a33a27df6e597dbc39485) on)

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: true
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL("http://browserify.org") // transparent background
  mainWindow.setBackgroundColor('#56cc5b10') // turns opaque brown
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

---

Update (2021): It is also possible to set the background color directly when creating the window: `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ backgroundColor: "#RRGGBB", ... });`

(thanks, @carlosrafaelgn)

---

Doing the same from renderer process seems to be buggy indeed.

However I noticed that if you un-focus then focus the window it'll start working properly.

```js
  <script>
    const { remote } = require('electron')
    const mainWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow()
    mainWindow.setBackgroundColor('#56cc5b10')
    mainWindow.blur()
    mainWindow.focus()
  </script>
```

Comment: I haven't tested this personally, but I've accepted it as the answer. Seems like a good workaround. Thanks very much!

Comment: For anyone coming here in 2021, it is also possible to set the background color directly when creating the window: `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ backgroundColor: "#RRGGBB", ... });`.